# Google App Scripts/ Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

При попытки использовать метод `Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`, [который есть в документации](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
к Google App Scripts (для Google Sheets), выдаётся ошибка : `Не удается обнаружить метод getRange(number,number,number,number)`. В чём может быть проблема? Почему в документации метод есть, а на деле его нет? При этом всё другие перегруженные методы кроме [этого](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)) также "не существуют".

Comment: Покажите код. Как вы Sheet получаете?

Comment: @Sergiks По ID таблицы: `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('/*Здесь идёт ID таблицы*/');`. И все методы работают, кроме указанных выше.

Comment: JavaScript - язык нетипизированный - `overloading` быть не может.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, проблема была в том, что метод `SpreadsheetApp.openById('/*Здесь идёт ID таблицы*/');` возвращает объект `SpreadSheet`, а не `Sheet`.

Comment: вот и славно : )